# SharePoint online trial

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

A couple months ago I was able to create an account on office-365 and have access to SharePoint online for like a couple of weeks.

I wanted to create a new test sharepoint just to check on how could I switch the entire site from classic to modern.
Once I went to the website I dont think now you can have that trying out sharepoint online.

[Here is what I get](https://products.office.com/de-de/sharepoint/compare-Sharepoint-plans)

Can anyone confirm this or maybe I just don't see it

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program

Answer (score 1):

These links show trials available:

Try here: https://products.office.com/de-de/try?market=de

or here: https://products.office.com/en-us/try

Comment: it seems that I need to add my paypal or credit card in order to have this first month free.

Comment: Should not be necessary. Try here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [trial A&Q](https://products.office.com/en-us/try), you do need to provide payment information to avoid interruptions with your service when the trial ends and enable future yearly payments with either International credit cards or PayPal (in some markets).

You can cancel any time during the trial period by clicking Turn off recurring billing in [My Account](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=401325).